# Dealing with occational i2c write errors, Python + RaspberryPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c

I have a RaspberryPi connected to a temperature/humidity sensor via its i2c bus.  Normally everything works great, I send write commands and listen for the response.  However every now and then the script crashes to a halt with the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "humidify.py", line 20, in <module>
    humidity = HTU21DF.read_humidity()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Projects/HTU21DF.py", line 51, in read_humidity
    pi.i2c_write_byte(handle, rdhumi) # send read humi command
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1861, in i2c_write_byte
    _pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_I2CWS, handle, byte_val))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 683, in _u2i
    raise error(error_text(v))
pigpio.error: 'I2C write failed'
```

I'm not looking to weed out what causes that occasional error, I want my script to wait a second and try the i2c write command again.  If I can make that work then I'll really be able to automate my system instead of having to check it constantly for crashes.

I'm a programming novice, so this is probably something basic.

Comment: I would try to figure out why it fails not ignore it, if you look at the source it tells you why the error is being raised, you can also set `pigpio.exceptions to False` and handle the return codes yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on exception handling. In python, you create a `try` block that contains the operation you're attempting, followed by one or more `except` blocks that each name one or more exception classes you are interested in handling. In this case, you're seeing `pigpio.error` exceptions.

What you might do is something like:

```
# try up to 3 times on a failure
success = False
caught_exception = None
for _ in range(3):
    try:
        pi.i2c_write_byte(...etc...)
        # if we get here, we succeeded, so break out of the loop
        success = True
        break
    except pigpio.error as e:
        print "error: %s"%(e)
        # wait a second for the retry
        time.sleep(1)

if not success:
    print "Failed after 3 retries!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Having been dealing with this issue myself, Raspberry Pi2 <-> MCP23016, the answer most likely is, you are using a MCP230xx and you need to tie the Reset pin high.